# How can I set default font Verdana in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

HTML Code:

```
    <textarea name="editor" id="editor" rows="9" style='width:79%;'></textarea>
```

Initialization:

```
    <script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {toolbar: [
    {name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'], items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'TextColor', 'BGColor']},
    {name: 'styles', items: ['Font', 'FontSize']},
    {name: 'insert', items: ['Image']},
    {name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi'], items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Blockquote', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock']},
    ]
 });
</script>
```

Now, I want to set default font Verdana. How can I set default font in the time of initialization.

Comment: try to look here: http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/How-do-you-set-default-font-and-default-font-size

Answer (score 0):

Add below   line in config.js of ckeditor

```
  config.font_defaultLabel = 'verdana';
  config.fontSize_defaultLabel = '12px';
  config.contentsCss = ['../contents.css'].concat(myFonts);
```

Add

```
    body
{
    /* Font */
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;

    /* Text color */
    color: #333;

    /* Remove the background color to make it transparent */
    background-color: #fff;

    margin: 20px;
}
```